# Asterisk Try Another If First is Busy

Tags: asterisk, voip, elastix, freepbx

I forward incoming calls to external numbers.
I do this with Follow me module for each number.
Sometimes I use one more external number in follow-me list, to call the second ona if the first one is busy. Bu it is calling the first one and ringing. First one is busy and it is still ringing. I does not call the second number.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Weirdest programming question ever?  Note to OP: SO is about computer programming (software) not phone programming.

Comment: Asterisk is a software too.

Comment: Show us the code you have written, we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provider or ATA not recognize busy signal. Unfortanly no way say what exactly happens, info provided not enought

Comment: Than you. I called my provider. They fixed the problem. I dont know why it happedened. Now it's ok.